# Is there a way to implement Rank() in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Does anyone know if there is a way to use the sql Rank() function with Hibernate?  I'm working on an app that will, in part, build a dependency tree for some artifacts in our database.  Now, using DbVis or SQLDev, I'd do something like

```
select  TemplateName, TemplateType, TemplateVersion
from (select TemplateName, TemplateType, TemplateVersion, rank() over (partition by TemplateName order by TemplateVersion Desc) r
       from ArtifactLookup where TemplateType='XX')
where r=1;
```

And would receive only the most recent version of each artifact that met the criteria of being type 'XX'.  How would I go about executing something like this in hibernate?

I have tried what little I can think of using HQL, but nothing seems to work.  I suspect I'm just over thinking things, but for the life of me, I cannot see how to do this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would be interested in an answer that doesn't resort to native sql, otherwise i have to manage all the association etc in native sql just to be able to use this filter.